# FIXED -- Voice prompt for Measurement concept from Library capsule does not work for Bixby runtime version 6

Tags: bixby

I have a very simple action where it takes a single parameter of type `measurement.Length`. if user does not provide the value for this parameter i want to prompt user for missing value. 
To do this i designed my action like below

```
action (AddDistance) {
  description (adding exercise)
  type(Search)
  collect {
    input (distance){
      type (measurement.Length)
      min (Required) max (One)
    }
  }
  output (Result)
}
```

I have added a NL training `[g:Result] add distance of (2 km)[v:measurement.Length]` which learned perfectly and giving this utterance works fine.

Now if i give the utterance like **"add distance"** the Bixby **does not prompt** for the missing input value instead give error with description

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined1000Cannot read property 'display' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined at

What should i do show prompt for this concept `measurement.Lenght` from Library capsule.
N.b. voice prompt works on runtime **version 5** with **no issue**.

Answer (score 0):

This is an important change, for runtime-version above 5, in order to use default dialog (which is true in many library capsules), developer needs to include the following override in capsule.bxb.

```
  runtime-version (6) {
    overrides {
      no-fallback-dialog-in-views (false)
    }
  }
```

The original bug cause the JS error has been fixed, but override is required to render library dialog.

Library capsules already got input-view and voice training handled. From your last capsule, change distance to `Required` in action model, and add following training missing `distance`. 
[image]

The input-view would be triggered, and let's use voice-input 
[image]

It runs fine to result-view, and confirmed on debugger
[image]

BTW, to replace the default "I need ..." message, add a dialog model as this

```
dialog (Elicitation) {
  match: measurement.Length
  template("How far would you like to run")
}
```

[image]

Comment: My runtime version was 6. When i rolled it back to version 5, the error was not showing anymore and prompt is working good now.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this. I was able to replicate with runtime-version(6). I will ask platform team for help, and will update here once learn more.

Comment: It appears to be a valid bug, please continue use runtime-version(5) while we are working on a fix. Sorry for the inconvenience and delay to your capsule development.

Comment: Hi, I just want to update you that the bug has been fixed. However for runtime-version above 5, it is required to have override no-fallback-dialog-in-views (false) to show the prompt. I've also updated answer.